# Write to separate files with different file names

Tags: c, c99

This is what I am trying to achieve:

> **Assume the user inputs are:**
>
> Generating random instances ...
>
> Enter the circuit board size MAX_X MAX_Y: 100 200
>
> Enter the number of points NUM_PT: 10
>
> Enter the number of random instances to be generated: 7
>
> your program will generate in total 7 instances, written into 7
> separate  files "instance10_j.txt", for j = 1, 2, 3, ...  Each
> instance has the rectangular area [0 ; 100] X [0 ; 200], and has 10
> points. The coordinates of a point is generated uniformly randomly
> within the rectangular area.  And your program makes sure there are no
> duplicate points within each instance.  If it is impossible for your
> program to generate these  files, prints out what an error is and quits.
> All these  files are saved in the current directory executing the
> command, and your program prints to the screen:
>
> instance10_1.txt generated
>
> instance10_2.txt generated
>
> instance10_3.txt generated
>
> instance10_4.txt generated
>
> instance10_5.txt generated
>
> instance10_6.txt generated
>
> instance10_7.txt generated ... done!

**This is what I have done so far:**

```
int writetofile(max_X, max_Y, numpt, random_inst);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 

{

  FILE *fp;

  int max_x, max_y, num_pt, rand_inst;
  int *x_coordinate, *y_coordinate;

  int inputfile = 0, outputfile = 0;
  int i;

  if (argc == 1)
    {
      /* to generate random instances, accepting parameters from stdin */
      printf("Generating random instances...");
      printf("Enter the circuit board size MAX_X MAX_Y:  ");
      scanf("%d %d", &max_x, &max_y);
      printf("Enter the number of points NUM_PT:  ");
      scanf("%d", &num_pt);
      printf("Enter the number of random instances to be generated:  ");
      scanf("%d", &rand_inst);
      return 1;
    }  
       /* MAIN FUNCTION CONTINUES FOR REMAINING WORK */
}

int writetofile(max_X, max_Y, numpt, random_inst)

{

  FILE *fp;
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i <= random_inst; i++)
    {
      /* NEED HELP HERE */
      fp = fopen(File with name instance[num_pt]_[rand_inst], "w");

      fprintf(fp, "#%s\n", argv[inputfile]);
      fprintf(fp, "#area [0, MAX_X] x [0, MAX_Y]\n");
      fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", max_x, max_y);
      fprintf(fp, "#number of points NUM_PT\n");
      fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num_pt);
      fprintf(fp, "#coordinates\n");
      for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++) 
      {
          fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", x_coordinate[i], y_coordinate[i]);
      }
    fprintf(fp, "#end of instance\n");
    fclose(fp);
```

I need to create random instances with no duplication but more importantly I should write them to separate files

My difficulty is in opening a file which would be named as `instance[num_pt]_[random_instances]`, which I think should be incorporated in the for loop.

I am using Ubuntu terminal to access my lab computer via ssh.

**Language: c99 ; Compiler: gcc**

Comment: "write them to separate files which I dont know how". Why not? Open file, write to file, close file. Repeat in a loop. Which part of that is causing you problems? Please be specific. We can't help you unless you tell us more specifically why you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: @kaylum I have to open the file with the format `instance[num_pt]_[random_instances]` which I cant figure out to do.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to form the file name? If so: `char name[MAX_LEN]; snprintf(name, MAX_LEN, "instance_%d_%d.txt", num_pt, random_inst); fopen(name, "w");`

Comment: @kaylum so I define the variable `name` and then use that to open my file to write? Is the variable defined inside the `for loop` since I have to increment the `random instances` in every file?

Comment: You can define the variable inside or outside the loop. The important thing is for the `snprintf` to be inside the loop as that forms the file name.

Comment: @kaylum What you suggested worked perfectly. Whenever you are free, could you post your comment as an answer so I could set it as an asnwer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like **Kaylum** mentioned.

```
char name[MAX_LEN];

/* Incorporate this into your for loop */

snprintf(name, MAX_LEN, "instance%d_%d.txt", num_pt, random_inst);
fopen(name, "w");
```