# Creating and writing in multiple txt files in C

Tags: c

I've got a code which creates j files (Node[j].ID) in a directory called (Nodes) and in those j files the code writes the info contained in NodeResults. At the moment the code doesn't neither create nor write in files because of the strcat function doesn't work. Please any idea how to correct the code in order to get the created files with the info contained in NodeResults on it?. Thanks in advance. Please find the code below:

```
{

    int period, j ;
    FILE*temporal;
    FILE* temp_time;
    char path[25];
    char* extention = ".txt";
    char s[30];
    char temporal2[25];
    long time_val = 0;
    _mkdir("Nodes");
    _mkdir("time"); 


    temp_time = fopen("Time/time.txt", "w");
    fprintf(temp_time, "%d,%d\n", ReportStep, Nperiods);
    fclose(temp_time);

    for ( j = 0; j < Nobjects[NODE]; j++ ) {
        /* File path writing */

        strcpy(temporal2,"Nodes/");
        strcat(temporal2, Node[j].ID);
        strcat(temporal2, extention);

        temporal= fopen(temporal2, "w"); 
    }                    
    for ( period = 1; period <= Nperiods; period++ ) {
        output_readNodeResults(period, j);
        fprintf(temporal, "%9.3f,%9.3f,%9.3f,%9.3f,%9.3f\n",
                    NodeResults[NODE_INFLOW],
                    NodeResults[NODE_OVERFLOW], 
                    NodeResults[NODE_DEPTH],
                    //NodeResults[NODE_HEAD],
                    NodeResults[NODE_VOLUME]);
    }
    fclose(temporal);

    return Nperiods;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and check a) the result of creating the filename - is it OK? and b) the result of `fopen` (that check should be in the code anyway - always check the result of `fopen`!)

Comment: A [MCVE] might help.

Comment: Isn't 25 a bit small for a filename? You might end up overwriting other variables.

Comment: I am pretty sure that strcat works

Comment: Try this question, it might help. [How to write to separate files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39940400/5504999)

Answer (score 4):

You open a bunch of files in the first `for` loop, but do not write anything to them.  At each iteration, you assign a new `FILE *` to variable `temporal`, overwriting any previous value.  Afterward, in your second `for` loop you write a bunch of output to the last file opened -- the one to which `temporal` refers at that point.

It looks like you want to move the body of the second for loop and the `fclose()` into the first `for` loop.

Comment: ah...I see.. a brace on the wrong line. The brace after open should be after close. This emphasizes again the importance of proper formating!

Comment: Thank you very much Guys for your time. I have formatted my code and corrected the brace. However, at the moment I'm having "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" means that I'm dereferencing a pointer that hasn't been initialized and therefore the error. On the other hand, I was traying to use sprintf to generate the files but now I got in fopen expression temporal2 that works as a buffer =Null

Answer (score 1):

I have properly formatted your code, and now John's comment immediately sticks out: the brace is on the wrong line, resulting in wrong for loops and blocks!

Should you have formatted the code properly yourself, you would have seen it immediately yourself!